# SwiftUI preview failure, Failed to launch swiftc: 'swiftc too many arguments' reason?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-previews

I have a large mixed language (obj-c, swift & c++) project, it builds and runs fine on all platforms

"Build for previews" also seems to complete fine.

Opening preview of a particular swift file fails, e.g.: [image]

Diagnostics gives:

```
Failed to launch swiftc.

==================================

|  HumanReadableNSError: NSInvalidArgumentException
|  
|  com.apple.dt.PreviewsFoundation.ExceptionError (0):
|  ==NSLocalizedFailureReason: too many arguments (4670) -- limit is 4096
```

I have managed to get previews to work previously. I switched to using prebuilt xcframeworks in the hope of improving the preview build performance, but has gone from slow to not working at all!

Comment: Same problem here. Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: I did get it working, but what I did was to rewrite the view somewhat - so there is nothing concrete I can attribute it to, I'm afraid.  It was quite a complex view which I broke down into smaller ones...so my best guess is some kind of cyclomatic complexity issue...

Comment: cool, but I have this error on a view that is literally

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }

Comment: Oh, wow.  Can you reproduce on a reasonably clean project?  Worth raising a radar bug I imagine...

Comment: Unfortunately not, the project is big and under NDA, but this is a newly generated module with an (almost) empty view and it doesn`t work

Comment: Turns out now I have this error on _every_ view in the project. Also, counted the number of .swift files in the project and it's 2033, so not related to the error message which in my case says `too many arguments (4323)`.

Comment: I suggest you create a new build target, and add just the swift UI files you want to preview - stub any of the model/data layer/observable object logic.